# Internet Options - How to use a proxy server for HTTP and HTTPS but not FTP

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy

I know how to set the proxy settings in Internet Explorer/Windows Internet Options via Connections > Lan Settings.

What I am not sure about is how to set it so HTTP and HTTPS use a proxy but I don't want FTP to use a proxy. Is this possible? If I leave the IP and Port empty for FTP will it not use a proxy or give an error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the Advanced button in Local Area Network (LAN) Settings and then uncheck the "Use the same proxy server for all protocols" checkbox.

You can then set up which protocols use which proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Just write in the proxy bypass list the protocol ftp://. It won't allow any ftp request passing through the proxy. See this article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361953.aspx