# Squid proxy server is blocking the FTP connection

Tags: networking, ftp, squid

I have set up a Squid proxy Server to restrict the websites. Now, I want to connect to a FTP server but the proxy server is somehow blocking the connection. I can connect to the FTP server from some other machine which is not using the proxy server. Any ideas or any help is very much appreciated. I'm completely clueless where to go from here.

Some additional info: Squid server is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance and aws workspace is getting proxied from this server to restrict the website usage.

Comment: What application are you using to connect to FTP? Have you checked that you have not enabled the use of a proxy for FTP connections?

Comment: I was using window explorer to connect to the ftp server and I'm not sure about your second question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internet Options - How to use a proxy server for HTTP and HTTPS but not FTP](https://superuser.com/questions/101239/internet-options-how-to-use-a-proxy-server-for-http-and-https-but-not-ftp)

Comment: I know that is an older post, but the options are the same. Just open internet options.

Comment: Thanks @Appleoddity but the thing is every request from aws workspace gets redirected to the Squid server. I don't manually do it from the browser

Comment: How is everything redirected? You had to have configured a proxy setting on the computer and with that comes the option of what protocols to forward.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm using this stack https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-add-dns-filtering-to-your-nat-instance-with-squid/ to configure the proxy settings.

Comment: That solution doesn’t even mention any other traffic than HTTP or HTTPS. The setup you created isn’t going to allow any traffic other than web traffic. IP forwarding needs to be turned on, or squid needs to be configured to proxy ftp as well. What will you do when you need other network services beyond ftp or http? Unless your environment is very focused with very predictable needs, the solution you used isn’t going to work very well, if at all.

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes the environment is very predictable. we only need FTP for now. Can you guide me with this IP forwarding technique, if it is possible? I suppose it uses iptables.

Comment: I am not real strong in this area so I can't type up instructions. The article you used does a good job at integrating AWS with Squid, but it does a bad job of telling you how to setup squid. The NAT rules are wrong and it is wrong suggesting you don't need to turn on ip_forwarding. Here's an overly simplistic setup that shows proper NAT rule examples and IP forwarding. The interface names may be different in AWS. https://linuxtechlab.com/squid-transparent-proxy-server-complete-configuration/ FTP is difficult because it uses dynamic ports and your security group will have to account for that.